# Jenkins Job Current "Log Status"

Tags: jenkins

I've got a job that runs for a long time (for example, it builds few solutions), Is there a way to know the current solution that is beind compiled on runtine?
I mean, the Log is very long, so sometimes is confusing to know what is the current compilation that is running. 
I want to know what is the current solution that is being compiled now... 
Any plugin or a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to diagnose problems if you split the job into multiple jobs (each one building a single solution). If you have dependencies between the different builds (i.e. one part of the build cannot happen until another part has completed), you can create a build pipeline, where once one job finishes, it triggers the next job in the pipeline. You can do this using the post-build action `Build other projects` in the job configuration.

There is also an excellent [build pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) which helps you visualize your build pipeline.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you have processes with LOTS of Solutions to build and it will be problematic to split them into seperate jobs. there will be hunderds of jobs ...

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that you *must* have the whole solution built in a single job, then one approach would be to use the Jenkins log parser plugin to display a cut-down version of your build log, which just highlights the key events you are interested in to diagnose such problems.

More details of this plugin can be found at:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem: I want to know in the runtime , what is the status (which project is being compiled now) ... As I read the Jenkins log parser plugin is a post build action.

Comment: I hear you. Could you give more detail of what your build job configuration looks like, particularly the command/s that are used to run the build? With that info we should be able to suggest some way of monitoring its progress outside of the Jenkins console output.

Comment: Using Jenkins we run a Final Builder process that builds all the solutions.

Comment: Ah I see - well in that case I don't think Jenkins can really help as it doesn't integrate with that tool (from what I can see). Maybe worth re-asking this question but framing it as more of a FinalBuilder related question (as in your case, all Jenkins is really doing is scheduling a build process). Or alternatively convince your workplace to adopt open source technologies, which usually play much more nicely with tools like Jenkins :) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two ideas for a possible solution but they needed to be implemented:

1. Adding a prefix for each row in the Log. The prefix could be a string.
for example, if there was a new Project Compilation started then the Log finds the line 
----- Rebuild All started: Project: PROJ1 , Configuration: Release x64 ------
Then it adds all the rows after it the prefix "Building PROJ1"
until the log reads the next project:
----- Rebuild All started: Project: PROJ2 , Configuration: Release x64 ------


2. Adding a the current project name that's building to the flashing Job status blue ball.
I mean, finding the current building project from the Log, then adding it next to the current job status (the flickering ball).